# C# Youtube - I want to delete video from my Youtube channel

Tags: c#, video, youtube

I want to delete videos from my YouTube channel which video ids are selected, though `MultiSelection` property of `ListBox` is on, code doesn't work, is there any other solution? I get such an error as follows:

`Execution of request failed: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/xxxxxx/uploads/System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+SelectedObjectCollection`

Here is my code:

```
public void delete() 
{

    YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(my app name,
                                                                  my dev key,
                                                                  my username, 
                                                                  my password);
    YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
    Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri(String.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{0}/uploads/{1}", my channel name, list.checkedItems));

    Video video = request.Retrieve<Video>(videoEntryUrl);

    request.Delete(video);
}
```

**Code for Populating the CheckedListBox**

```
Feed<Video> videoFeed;

string feedUrl = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";

videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));

foreach (Video entry in videoFeed.Entries)
{
    list.Items.Add(entry.VideoId,0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok...I think the key here is to get the data out of the object collection - and an easy way to do that is with a `foreach` loop.  I'm not familiar with the YouTube API so I don't know what format it expects the video ID in (for multiple videos), but for purposes of this example I'll use a comma.

```
string videoIDs = "";

foreach (object vidID in list.CheckedItems)
{

    videoIDs = videoIDs + vidID.ToString() + ",";
}

videoIDs = videoIDs.Substring(0, videoIDs.Length - 1);
```

Basically, the above code loops through the `CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection` and gets the video IDs, which is what you are storing in the CheckedBoxList from the code you provided.

Then you can simply use the `videoIDs` string in your code:

```
Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri(String.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{0}/uploads/{1}", my channel name, videoIDs));
```

Again, this is a general approach - you will need to modify the code to fit the YouTube API.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Feed<Video> videoFeed;


            string feedUrl = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";


            videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));

            foreach (Video entry in videoFeed.Entries)
            {
                list.Items.Add(entry.VideoId,0);







            }
```